# How many different ways can 10 people be lined up if there's two pairs that don't get along?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I started by defining the total amount of permutations as 10!

Then, instead of calculating the number of combinations in which both pairs of people end up being separated, I calculated the complementary probability (combinations in which they do end up together):

2!*8!*9 = 2*9! for the first pair and 2!*8!*9 = 2*9! for the second pair

Therefore, we would have 10!-2*2*9!

And after applying exclusion-inclusion principle...

Number of possible combinations = 10!-2*2*9!+2*2*8! = 2338560

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you mean permutations in the first sentence.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Correct use of inclusion-exclusion.  It may have been nice to have heard an explanation for why $2\cdot 9!$ and $2\cdot 2\cdot 8!$ are correct values to use for a full and complete explanation, but for just checking answers what you wrote is fine.